# Compile time evaluation of literal type members

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have two literal types **A** and **B** defined as below. Literal type **B** can be initialized at compile time from literal type **A**. A third *non-literal* type **C** contains the literal type **B** as a member. The question is, if we initialize **a** at compile time and pass it to **C**'s constructor, is **b** initialized at compile time as well? Since **C** is a non-literal type, its member **v** is not initialized at compile time. However, is there a partial compile time initialization happening for **b**? If that is the case, would a *constexpr* member function such as **f** evaluate at compile time if used inside **C**? Obviously we can not use such function at compile time outside the struct **C**, since we can not declare **C**'s objects to be *constexpr*.

```
struct A {
    constexpr A(int num): num{num} {}
    int num;
};

struct B {
    constexpr B(A a): num{a.num} {}
    int num;
};

template<typename T>
struct C {
    C(A a, std::initializer_list<T> data): b{a}, v{data} {}

    constexpr int f() const {
        return b.num + 42;
    }

    B b;
    std::vector<T> v;
};

int main() {
     constexpr A a {4};
     C<int> c {a, {5}};
}
```

Comment: The standard does not define "compile time". You can only ask whether something is a constant expression or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `f` is illegal, because it is a non-`static` `constexpr` member of a non-literal class.  GCC 6.1 gives the following error:

```
error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'int C::f() const' is not a literal type
note: 'C' is not literal because:
note: 'C' has a non-trivial destructor
```

As such, it is meaningless to ask whether the `B` data member of `C` is evaluated at compile time, since there is no way to observe when it is evaluated.

Comment: That is true! Thank you for pointing that out. 

If  **C** is templated, the code compiles without errors on g++ 5.3.0 . The toy example above was inspired by a templated class, I forgot to compile after adding **f()**. I edited the question, it should compile without issues now.

Comment: @TeodorNikolov But now you have no legal instantiations, strictly speaking, since no possible T could make it a literal class.

Comment: @SebastianRedl not quite; I think it's possible to envisage specializations of `std::vector` and `std::allocator` for a user-provided `T` such that the destructor of the former could be trivial while still complying with [namespace.std]/2. Also, I'm not sure whether "valid" in [temp.res]/8 is intended to cover [namespace.std]/2 violations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure user-provided specializations of vector are UB, but not entirely sure.

Comment: @SebastianRedl nah, it's not prohibited in [container] so if it meets the requirements it's fine: "A program may add a template specialization
for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
prohibited." ([namespace.std]/1, not [namespace.std]/2 as I incorrectly wrote above.)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, unless the end result is required at compile time, any call to a constexpr function *may*, but does not *have to* be evaluated at compile time. Since the constructor of `C` doesn't need its `B` argument at compile time, it's up to the compiler if it wants to evaluate the conversion early or generate code.

Generally speaking, I believe you will find that the compiler, at any optimization level greater than zero, will inline and evaluate the constructors so far as to simply assign 4 to the appropriate place inside the `C` instance and directly call the vector constructor, if it doesn't just inline that as well and unroll the initialization loop, basically ending up with code that looks something like this:

```
int main() {
  C c = UNINITIALIZED;
  c.b.num = 4;
  c.v._buffer = operator new(sizeof(int) * _MINIMUM_ELEMENTS);
  c.v._capacity = _MINIMUM_ELEMENTS;
  c.v._size = 1;
  c.v._buffer[0] = 5;
}
```

The only way to find out is to compile the code and let the compiler emit the assembly it generates.